# Send <div> content to string, edit it, and then replace it

Tags: javascript, html

I need to extract a large amount of text from a `<div>`, put it into a string through JavaScript's `.innerHTML`, then split it through `.split("")`. From here, I need to get the caret's location (which I have working), and insert a new tag there.

```
var newtext = $('outputcontent').innerHTML.split("");
    var wheretoinsert = getCaretPos($('outputcontent'));
    newtext[wheretoinsert] += "<div>Content goes here</div>";
    $('outputcontent').innerHTML = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < newtext.length; i++){
        $('outputcontent').innerHTML += newtext[i];
    }
```

I am currently doing this by resetting the content of the `<div>` and then adding each of the split portions in a for statement. The problem I am having is that instead of the div remaining the same with the new content, it will change to have each of the html tags visible in the text, such as:

```
RE; Incorporation and Organization
```

as a line of text will be rewritten as:

```
 <div class="leftAlign"> <b> <u> RE; Incorporation and Organization </u> </b>...
```

How would I change this so that the html tags will remain functional as tags, and not get escaped into the string?
Note that I am **NOT** using jQuery or any other plugins, and cannot do so.

Comment: Have you tried $(‘outputcontent’).innerHTML = newtext instead of looping over each character and adding one by one?

Comment: "Note that I am NOT using jQuery" : I'm confused.  The code segment you posted looks like jQuery ?

Comment: try DOM operation

Comment: If you give specific example, I can give you an answer.

Comment: @GabrielGates I managed to solve this by using the array.join argument, which for some reason I didn't think of using before your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @devlincarnate It looks like jQuery since I remade jQuery's selector by setting $("") the same as document.getElementById("")

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(I'm assuming `$` is a function that returns an `Element`.)</sup>

[`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) isn't just a string; it's doing work behind the scenes. When you set it, the entire string is parsed into a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) which is used to replace the contents of the `Element`. When you build it up character by character, `Element.innerHTML` only sees a `"<"`, which it dutifully transforms into `"&lt;"`:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
console.log('Original content:', div.innerHTML);

const newContent = '<hr>'.split('');
for (let i = 0; i < newContent.length; ++i) {
  div.innerHTML += newContent[i];
  console.log(`After inserting character ${i}: ${div.innerHTML}`);
}
```

```html
<div><em>Original is fine</em></div>
```

Instead of looping over your `newtext` array, [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it back into a string before sending it to `innerHTML`:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
console.log('Original content:', div.innerHTML);

const newContent = '<hr>'.split('');
div.innerHTML = newContent.join('');
console.log('After replacing with newContent:', div.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div><em>Original is fine</em></div>
```